# How can I format text in GWT label widget

Tags: gwt, widget

I would like to break a long line of text assigned to the standard Label widget in GWT.
I was experimenting with inline `<br />` elements but with no success.

Something like this:

```
label = "My very very very long<br />long long text"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the HTML widget, which extends the standard Label widget, and adds support for interpreting HTML tags.

See the [JavaDoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html).

Comment: I would just add that when using the HTML widget you should use the setHTML() method as the setText() method will just accept the string as text

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS to style the label to fit a given with and drop the `<br/>` all together.

Comment: You wrote <br> literally, and so it interprets it as a linebreak. Edit it to <br%gt;

Comment: The HTML widget is smart enough to know that <br /> is a HTML element and creates a correct output.

Comment: By the way CSS will not work in my case as I want to split the text at a exact location.

Comment: 'tis funny Steve means the actual SO-post while Drejc refers to the GWT widget :)